# Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component while removing items from ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, data-binding, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection which is bound to an ItemsControl as it's ItemsSource (TwoWay mode). For some weird scrolling issue, I had to come up with a hack to remove all the items from this collection before setting it again. Because if I reinstantiate this collection I run into that scrolling issue (which is not worth explaining here I suppose). So here is what I do:

```
var itemsToRemove = MyCollection.ToList();
foreach (var itemToRemove in itemsToRemove)
{
    MyCollection.Remove(itemToRemove);
}
// Add items to the collection
```

I get this error while trying to remove items from this collection: `Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component`. It occurs only if the collection is relatively large (more than 10 items) and it does not occur for the very first item but for some item in middle of the collection (may have something to do with the binding?).

Note: I cannot use `MyCollection.Clear()` since it is resulting into the same scrolling issue which I am trying to work around.

Answer (score 0):

First of HRESULT E_FAIL isn't a good failure because it can have many sources. But in your case it's actually really simple.

You converted your Collection to a list to iterate through it with foreach. In your foreach, you want to remove an item out of your list. But this is still referenced in the List, and the order of the List is locked by the foreach interator. So to solve this, you need to clear your Collection / List in a for loop where no iterator is blocking the referenced List.

EDIT

foreach .... ITERATOR Variable
{...LOCKED}

So as long as you are in a foreach loop, the iterator of the variable you want to go through, like a list with objects, the order and count of the list is locked. So you cannot remove, add items in the list, because the iterator locks it. That is needed because otherwise the iterator would say Next element is H but actually it is G and you skip G because the iterator is wrong because you manipulated the list. That's why it is locked.

The collection.ToList creates a new list, with referenced Items to the collection. So when the Iterator locks the list, the collection is also locked.

To remove elements now, you have to do it this way

```
for( int i = 0; i ++; i < List.Count())
{
      collection.removeat(i)
}
```

Comment: I am not very sure if I understand what you just said. Some code would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It gives 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' since same collection is being modified (while removing items). So next time when it goes inside to remove the item at index say 2, the item might have been moved to index 1. I will fix this and see if this works.

Comment: So I did this: for (int i = itemsToRemove.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        MyCollection.RemoveAt(i);
                    }  But it gave the same exception Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Comment: So if still the same error occurs, sorry for my wrong answer. Could you please put a try catch block around your remove code, so we get a better view of the error, because the error you mention is a COM related one, and doesn't tell something about the things happening below.

Comment: Strangely, I am not seeing this error by executing the exact same flow now. It makes me wonder if it is something related to timing issue. Since this collection bound as an item source of the items control (flipview).